# php count words in array of variables

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array of variable strings and I want to count all the commas and find the total commas in all the strings. I know that I have to use the explode and foreach but don't know how to put them together and how to add all the commas at the end...

```
 $log1 = "one, two, three,";

 $log2 = "red, blye, green,";

 $log3 = "sunny day, snowy day, nice one,";

 $main_log = array(log1, log2, log3);
```

Comment: How do u expect the final result to be? What do you expect `$main_log` to be?

Comment: just a number as a variable, like $main_log which in the case above will be 9

Comment: And what is `blye` color? :)

Comment: Plus there will is syntax error.... it should be `$main_log=array($log1, $log2, $log3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make some corrections. Concatenate all the strings instead of pushing them into an array in the manner it has been done in following code;

```
$log1 = "one, two, three,";

 $log2 = "red, blye, green,";

 $log3 = "sunny day, snowy day, nice one,";

 $main_log = $log1.$log2.$log3;
 echo substr_count($main_log, ','); //prints 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to count commas - just do it:

```
array_sum(array_map(function($str){
  return substr_count($str, ',');
}, $main_log));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
substr_count($string, ',');
```

For the array.... @vp_arth 's solution would work...

```
$log1 = "one, two, three,";

$log2 = "red, blye, green,";

$log3 = "sunny day, snowy day, nice one,";

$main_log = array($log1, $log2, $log3);

$result= array_sum(array_map(function($str){
  return substr_count($str, ',');
}, $main_log));


echo $result;
```

Comment: `substr_count()` will work on a string only. `$main_log` is a array

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code like this -

```
$log1 = "one, two, three";
$log2 = "red, blye, green";
$log3 = "sunny day, snowy day, nice one";

$arr1 = explode(',', $log1);
$arr2 = explode(',', $log2);
$arr3 = explode(',', $log3);


$main_log = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);   //Array merge
$count = array_count_values($main_log); //Total count the array values
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another couple solutions:

```
$log1 = "one, two, three,";
$log2 = "red, blye, green,";
$log3 = "sunny day, snowy day, nice one,";

$main_log = $log1.$log2.$log3;

echo count(explode(',',$main_log))-1;

echo substr_count($main_log, ',');
```